# Microsoft ODBC Driver For Hive

Tags: azure, odbc, hive, bigdata

I'm interested to connect Sisense (BI intelligence software) running on Windows Server 2008 R2 to Hive server.
I downloaded Microsoft ODBC driver for Hive from here:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=37134
```

Is Microsoft ODBC Driver For Hive able to connect to non-Azure Hive?
My Hive runs on Redhat, will Microsoft ODBC Driver connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft will only support their Hive ODBC driver is when used with HDinsight. However, the Hive protocol is open and implemented by everyone. What distro of Hive are you running on Redhat? You should check to see if your particular distro supplies an ODBC driver. I'm aware that the pure Hadoop distro vendors all supply ODBC drivers already: Cloudera, Hortonworks & MapR.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hadoop distro you're using, you should probably use the Cloudera or HortonWorks ODBC driver.

I would recommend the HortonWorks one (http://hortonworks.com/products/hdp-2/#add_ons) since their distribution is closest to Hive core and will be likely be better suited to Windows as well. If you're using a 1.3 strand version, you may do better with http://hortonworks.com/products/hdp-1-3/#add_ons.